# How to customize a column using template in kendo gantt chart?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-gantt

I would like to add checkbox to my gantt chart which is a kendo gantt widget. In kendo grid this can be achieved using custom templates. How do I achieve the same thing in kendo gantt?

Comment: did you find a way to apply a custom template over a specific column?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs you can customize templates for

- [editable popup](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#configuration-editable.template)
- [task](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/task-template)
- [toolbar](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#configuration-toolbar)
- [tooltip](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#configuration-tooltip.visible)
- [views](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#configuration-views)

But you can't use templates for Gantt's columns. You didn't specify where exactly you would like to have your checkbox, but I'd assume it's for every task.

You can either customize the template for edit popup for each task, or you can simply add editable column for the schema field with type "boolean" to have a checkbox (you need to double click the "true/false" value to edit)
[example dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ogILU)

Comment: thank you rsobon for the reply. I want to add template for gantt columns. I followed http://www.telerik.com/forums/gantt-custom-column-template and implemented checkboxes. However It is not giving those flexibilities which kendo grid used to provide.